# Remap concatinated values in mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, explode

I have 2 mysql tables one contains category mapping relationships between a supplier and our store: Basically what we call their categories eg ~ denotes sub category level:

Cateogry Mapping Relationship Table

```
Supplier Cat..........| Our Cat.....
dogs~leashes~long.....| pets~walking
dogs~leashes~long.....| pets~travel
dogs~leashes~short....| pets~walking
dogs~leashes~nylon....| pets~walking
dogs~feeding .........| pets~feeding
```

the other  table contains supplier item ids with the categories that the supplier has the products in. Multiple categories are concatenated in the same field with a ','.

Such as the following:

Supplier Item Table

```
Supplier item ID...| Supplier item Categories
28374  ............| dogs~leashes~long,dogs~leashes~nylon
```

My task is to replace the item paths in the supplier list with the correct paths from our store category list so I can put them in our database.

So the result of the php / mysql function Im trying to build for the above data modification would be (I dont care if I run this in php or mysql which ever is easier to get the job done.):

```
Supplier item..| Supplier item Categories ..............| New item Categories
28374  ........| dogs~leashes~long,dogs~leashes~nylon ..|pets~travel,pets~walking
```

Im not sure how to handle the concatenated field and I would appreciate any help at all

thank you

Comment: Is this a batch job you are doing or is it something that has to be processed during a Web request?  Basically I am wondering how fast or an execution time you need?

Answer (score 0):

1. write a query that selects id,cat from supplier item table
2. In a php loop split the category by ',' and do a select to get your category
3. write into a new table id/your category
4. check new table for validity
5. delete old table and rename new table